# Batch Loop menu (multiple selection)

Tags: arrays, loops, batch-file, menu, batch-processing

I'm trying to set up a batch menu that allows for multiple selection at once then runs all the functions. Sequence that functions are not relevant just the fact that the functions will be run with out, outside errors. Here is the code that I have so far.

```
@Echo off
Echo Please Enter the corrasponding numbers separated by a space or colon (,) 
Echo for the Options that you would like to run e.g. 1 4,3 2
Echo Option #1 
Echo Option #2  
Echo Option #3  
Echo Option #4
Echo.

SET /P Selection=Please Select Restore Options? 
echo You chose: %Selection% 

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
Set /a index = 0
FOR %%A IN (%Selection%) DO (
SET Array[!index!] = %%A
SET /a index += 1
)

for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set Array[') DO (
set string=%%s
set string=%string: =%
echo %string%
Call :Opt%string%
)

pause
goto :EOF


:Opt1
ECHO Option 1's code
GOTO :EOF

:Opt2
ECHO Option 2's code
GOTO :EOF

:Opt3
ECHO Option 3's code
GOTO :EOF

:Opt4
ECHO Option 4's code
GOTO :EOF
```

The code I have works to the point where trying to call the Array veriable and attach it to a Call e.g. `Call :Opt%%s`
The probelm I have is that the array variable keeps coming out with a space proceeding the selected variable. So I have tried combating this with set `string=%string:=%` but I keep getting an error.

**Error :**

> either echo is off and only opt is getting called with out the selected variable.

Help with this would be amazing, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The start of the problems is

```
SET Array[!index!] = %%A
------------------^-^---- = aditional spaces
```

This aditional spaces are used, so you end with a variable with an aditional space in its name and an aditional space in its value. So, better use

```
SET "Array[!index!]=%%A"
```

The reason for the `echo` error is you forget to use delayed expansion in the `for %%s` loop. You change the `%string%` variable inside the loop and try to use the changed value inside the same loop.

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set Array[') DO (
    set "string=%%s"
    set "string=!string: =!"
    echo !string!
    Call :Opt!string!
)
```

But the corrections indicated in the original `set` make it unnecessary to replace the spaces.

Answer (score 2):

MC ND solved most of the problems with your code.

One trivial issue - the punctuation is a comma, not a colon ;-)

But a more serious issue, what if the user entered 3 choices, and there already was a variable named Array[4]? It would run that extra value that hadn't been entered by the user. It would even attempt to run a value stored in Array[anythingGoes.

You've got the number of values stored in "index", so why not use it? A more common and simpler way to iterate the array is to use a FOR /L loop. This also preserves the original order. Your way would change the order once you get 10 or more entries. (I know you say order doesn't matter, but why change the order if you don't have to?)

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%N in (1 1 %index%) do (
  echo !Array[%%N]!
  call :Opt!Array[%%N]!
)
```

But I don't see a reason to mess with an array at all. Your loop that parses the user input could simply call the functions directly. Now you don't even need delayed expansion.

```
for %%A in (%Selection%) do (
  echo %%A
  call :Opt%%A
)
```

Comment: Thanks dbenham that last peace of code actually makes this script a whole lot simpler.